# django.db.migrations.exceptions.InvalidBasesError: Cannot resolve bases

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-admin

I'm creating multiple types of users with different permissions and hierarchy by extending AbstractBaseUser in django 3.1. All users are Employee, and there is an exploitation administrator type who is a kind of superuser, a Supervisor who has multiple Drivers under his control and there is a controller who is a independent User. But I get an errors about the models that I used. this is my models definition in models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField
from django.contrib.gis.db import models as gis_models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin
from .managers import EmployeeManager


class Employee(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=False, null=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=False, null=False)
    registration_number = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(unique=True, blank=False, null=False)
    email = models.EmailField()
    cni = models.CharField(max_length=18, blank=True)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='DriversPictures/', max_length=100, blank=True)
    matricule_cnss = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True)
    driving_licence = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True)
    recruitment_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, blank=True)
    phone = PhoneNumberField(blank=True, help_text='numéro de telephone')
    adress = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True)
    city_id = models.ForeignKey('City', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    region_id = models.ForeignKey('Region', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
#   user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
#   roles = models.ManyToManyField('Role')
    is_exploitation_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_supervisor = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_controlor = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_driver = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    vehicle_id = models.ForeignKey('Vehicle', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'registration_number'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email']

    objects = EmployeeManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return (self.registration_number, self.first_name, self.last_name)


class Supervisor(Employee):
    zone_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True)


class Driver(Employee):
    supervisor_id = models.ForeignKey('Supervisor', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    projects = models.ManyToManyField('Client', through='ProjectFleet')



class Controlor(Employee):
    supervisor_id = models.ForeignKey('Supervisor', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    gaz_station_id = models.ForeignKey('GazStation', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

The admin.py I want to have the registration_number to be the unique field for authentication:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from .forms import EmployeeCreationForm, EmployeeChangeForm
from .models import Employee


class EmployeeAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_form = EmployeeCreationForm
    form = EmployeeChangeForm
    model = Employee
    list_display = ('email', 'is_active', 'is_exploitation_admin', 'is_supervisor', 'is_controlor', 'is_driver',)
    list_filter = ('registration_number', 'email', 'is_active', 'is_exploitation_admin', 'is_supervisor', 'is_controlor', 'is_driver',)
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('registration_number', 'email', 'password')}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_active', 'is_exploitation_admin', 'is_supervisor', 'is_controlor', 'is_driver')}),
    )
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('registration_number', 'email', 'password1', 'password2', 'is_active', 'is_exploitation_admin', 'is_supervisor', 'is_controlor', 'is_driver')}
        ),
    )
    search_fields = ('email','registration_number', 'first_name','last_name')
    ordering = ('registration_number', 'last_name')


admin.site.register(Employee, EmployeeAdmin)
```

the **managers.py** is:

```
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import BaseUserManager
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _


class EmployeeManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, first_name, last_name, password, **extra_fields):
        if not last_name:
            raise ValueError(_('Le nom est obligatoire'))
        if not first_name:
            raise ValueError(_('Le prenom est obligatoire'))
        user = self.model(first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, first_name, last_name, mail, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_exploitation_admin', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_supervisor', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_controlor', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_driver', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_staff=True.'))
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.'))
        return self.create_user(first_name, last_name, email, password, **extra_fields)
```

The Error message is :

```
(myEnv) mohammed@Laptop:~/Projects/Transport_Project$ python3 manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: Drivers_App_Management, admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying Drivers_App_Management.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/mohammed/anaconda3/envs/myEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/mohammed/anaconda3/envs/myEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/mohammed/anaconda3/envs/myEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/mohammed/anaconda3/envs/myEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/mohammed/anaconda3/envs/myEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 85, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mohammed/anaconda3/envs/myEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 245, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "/home/mohammed/anaconda3/envs/myEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/mohammed/anaconda3/envs/myEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/mohammed/anaconda3/envs/myEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 227, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/home/mohammed/anaconda3/envs/myEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 114, in apply
    operation.state_forwards(self.app_label, project_state)
  File "/home/mohammed/anaconda3/envs/myEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/models.py", line 86, in state_forwards
    list(self.managers),
  File "/home/mohammed/anaconda3/envs/myEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/state.py", line 95, in add_model
    self.reload_model(app_label, model_name)
  File "/home/mohammed/anaconda3/envs/myEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/state.py", line 156, in reload_model
    self._reload(related_models)
  File "/home/mohammed/anaconda3/envs/myEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/state.py", line 189, in _reload
    self.apps.render_multiple(states_to_be_rendered)
  File "/home/mohammed/anaconda3/envs/myEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/state.py", line 314, in render_multiple
    "for more" % (new_unrendered_models, get_docs_version())
django.db.migrations.exceptions.InvalidBasesError: Cannot resolve bases for [<ModelState: 'Drivers_App_Management.Driver'>]
This can happen if you are inheriting models from an app with migrations (e.g. contrib.auth)
 in an app with no migrations; see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/migrations/#dependencies for more
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by changing the order of models creation in the ***migrations/001_initial.py***, where I found that django tried to create the model **Driver** *model* before **Employee** *model* and that causes error because the Driver model inherit from Employee.